# Eloquent with multiple where

Tags: laravel

I want to get the conferences where the status column in conferences table is equal "P" and also that have the end_date < now(). So I have this query:

```
 $publishedConferences = 
 $user->conferences()->
 where(['status', '=', 'P'], 
 ['end_date','<', now()])->paginate($pageLimit);
```

But like this is not working it appear:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0'
in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate 
from `conferences` where `conferences`.`organizer_id` = 4 
and `conferences`.`organizer_id` is not null
and (`0` = status and `1` = = and `2` = P))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with closure:

```
$publishedConferences = 
   $user->conferences()->
   where(function ($query) {
     $query->where('status', '=', 'P');
     $query->where('end_date','<', now());
   })
   ->paginate($pageLimit);
```

Answer (score 3):

Referencing: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

You can easily combine multiple where clauses, just by adding multiple `where()`

```
        $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                ->where('name', 'John')
                ->get();
```

if you need an `OR` operator

```
         $users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                ->orWhere('name', 'John')
                ->get();
```

You can also do it this way with `whereColumn`, just note that they are using the `and` operator:

```
      $users = DB::table('users')
         ->whereColumn([
                 ['first_name', '=', 'last_name'],
                 ['updated_at', '>', 'created_at']
         ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, but your parameters to `where()` are a little off.

When passing an array of where clauses, it needs to be an array of arrays. You just need to wrap your parameters in another array:

```
$publishedConferences = $user->conferences()
    ->where([
        ['status', '=', 'P'],
        ['end_date','<', now()]
    ])
    ->paginate($pageLimit);
```

This is effectively the same as using a closure and adding the where clauses to the query individually.

Answer (score 0):

This is cleaner in my opinion.

```
$whereData = [
 ['status', 'P'],
 ['end_date', '<', now()]
];

$publishedConferences = 
 $user->conferences()->
 where($whereData)->
paginate($pageLimit);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following:

```
  $publishedConferences = $user->conferences()->where('status', 'P')->where('end_date','<',Carbon::now())->paginate($pageLimit);
```